# Permission denied error encountered when using laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, storage, laravel-10, laravel-dompdf

hello guys im trying to save a docx file as a pdf and when i save it its give me an error

```
public function attr(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form data here as needed
    
        // Get the form data
        $title = $request->input('title');

 
        // Load the Word template
        $template = new TemplateProcessor(storage_path('app/public/docs/AR.docx'));
    
        // Replace placeholders with form data
        $template->setValue('title', $title);
    
        // Save the modified Word document
        $outputPathDocx = storage_path('app/public/docs/AR_' . uniqid() . '.docx');
        $template->saveAs($outputPathDocx);
    
        // Convert Word to PDF using Dompdf
        $outputPathPdf = storage_path('app/public/pdfs/attr/AR_' . uniqid() . '.pdf');
        $pdf = PDF::loadFile($outputPathDocx);
        $pdf->save($outputPathPdf);
    
        // to download the generated PDF:
        return response()->download($outputPathPdf, 'AR.pdf');
    }
```

but i got this problem

`Permission denied on C:\Users\nourd\OneDrive\Desktop\dashboard\storage\app\public\docs\AR_6558f287364af.docx. The communication protocol is not supported.`

in this **LINE**

`$pdf = PDF::loadFile($outputPathDocx);`

i try a lot to resolve this problem

Comment: If you use something like `file_get_contents('C:\Users\nourd\OneDrive\Desktop\dashboard\storage\app\public\docs\AR_6558f287364af.docx')`, does this also give permission error?

Comment: no ,its not give me  permission error

Comment: im just trying to convert docx to pdf without losing the style, i try dompdf its work but its convert it without style